# Difficulty in integrating a separate project into other project

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

I have a project which has gui consisting of three buttons.Now one of these button is to be associated with other activity.I have developed the code for this activity separately and tested it but now when I'm integrating this in my main gui project it is showing errors.(Clicking on button will get me the current location on google maps).

Here is my log cat :

```
10-27 01:45:44.533: E/ActivityThread(357): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
10-27 01:45:44.563: E/ActivityThread(357): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
10-27 01:45:44.633: D/AndroidRuntime(357): Shutting down VM
10-27 01:45:44.633: W/dalvikvm(357): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
10-27 01:45:44.643: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gui/com.example.gui.LocationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.example.gui.LocationActivity.onCreate(LocationActivity.java:50)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
10-27 01:45:44.653: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  ... 11 more
10-27 01:45:44.693: I/dalvikvm(357): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
10-27 01:45:44.693: E/dalvikvm(357): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Comment: Please post your onCreate message and point out which line is 50, that is where you are getting the NullPointerException as your exception states.

Comment: Here is my LocationActivity.java file http://pastebin.com/k24Nu9WA     this is main.xml file http://pastebin.com/TB4hiSFY  and this is manifest file http://pastebin.com/LGS4GGhT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error message because at line 50 when you call

```
map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

your `map` variable is null. Please post your main.xml file as that is where your `onCreate` method is looking for views when you call `findViewById` since you called

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: I'm giving links of all the files Here is my LocationActivity.java file pastebin.com/k24Nu9WA , this is main.xml file pastebin.com/TB4hiSFY and this is manifest file pastebin.com/LGS4GGhT